# Datagridviewlink Cell not updated

Tags: c#, datagridview

In My Application Datagridview has link column .I want to disable that cell on particular condition.

on load event of form first i have bound datagridview from database and than disable cell by making it to textboxcolumn . but dont know why it is not working if write the same code on button click event than it works fine . what is problem going on?

Code is as below:

```
for (int k = 0; k < dgvMonthplan.Rows.Count; k++)
{
     if (dgvMonthplan.Rows[k].Cells["month"].Value.ToString() == curr_mon && dgvMonthplan.Rows[k].Cells["year"].Value.ToString() == curr_year)
     {
          DataGridViewTextBoxCell txtcell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
          txtcell.Style.BackColor = Color.YellowGreen;
          dgvMonthplan.Rows[k].Cells["delete"] = txtcell;                                                          
     }
}
```

Comment: @soner Thanks i was trying to edit the same but i could not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got My solution .

I was calling this child form from MDI parent Form Like:

```
         NextFrm objfrm = new NextFrm ();
         objfrm .MdiParent = this;
         objfrm .Show();
```

I Comment this line `objfrm .MdiParent` and So It worked Finally .you can use showdialog() insted of show()